# remove duplicate elements in dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove duplicate elements in column 'p1' and 'p2' i.e should the elements already occurred in column 'p1' it should not reappear in 'p2' or any subsequent column. For eg, for the code below, only 'a b' and 'c d' will remain.

Whats the effecient way of doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'p1':['a','b','a','a','b','d','c'],
                'p2':['b','a','c','d','c','a','d'],
                'value':[1,1,2,3,5,3,5]})
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `value`, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series`, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html), [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.set_index('value').stack().drop_duplicates().unstack().reset_index()
   value    p1 p2
0      1     a  b
1      2  None  c
2      3  None  d
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, maybe let me rephrase my question, p1 and p2 got to be a pair. However, whatever already happen in any of my p1 or p2, i do not wish the item to reappear in any of my subsequent p1 or p2

Comment: IIUC you need `print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['p1','p2'])` ?

Comment: Maybe understand - you need remove all rows in output `df` with `None` values?

Comment: I would like to drop the row if p1 duplicate in p2. what's the efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Desired output is `print pd.DataFrame({'p2': {1: 'a', 4: 'c'}, 'p1': {1: 'b', 4: 'b'}, 'value': {1: 1, 4: 5}})` ?

Comment: desired output
    pd.DataFrame({'p2': {0: 'b', 6: 'd'}, 
              'p1': {0: 'a', 6: 'c'},
              'value': {0: 1, 6: 5}})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108749/discussion-between-jezrael-and-shinjiono).

Answer (score 0):

> Series( pd.DataFrame({'p1':['a','b','a','a','b','d','c'],'p2':['b','a','c','d','c','a','d'],'value':[1,1,2,3,5,3,5]}).values.ravel()).unique()

I'll post output as soon as I get pandas installed in my virtualenv.

Comment: But OP wants remove duplicates only from `p1` and `p2`. Next problem is lost index, if `df` is created by constructor.